# Using Gram-Schmidt to get Orthonormal basis

Tags: linear-algebra, algebra-precalculus

Let me start by saying I am 100% comfortable with Gram-Schmidt and normalizing. This particular question appears to be a poorly written polynomial. Thus, can someone please check through this and or let me know if I am right?

The inner product is defined as follows and I have to find an orthonormal basis.
$\langle \begin{bmatrix}
        a \\
        b \\
          \end{bmatrix}, \begin{bmatrix}
        c \\
        d \\
        \end{bmatrix}\rangle= ac+\frac12 (ad+bc)+bd$

---

I have found 
$W_1=\begin{bmatrix}
        a \\
        b \\
        \end{bmatrix}$ with $||W_1||=\sqrt{a^2+ab+b^2}$

$W_2=\begin{bmatrix}
        \frac{c-ca^2-\frac12acb-\frac12da^2-adb}{a^2+ab+b^2} \\
        \frac{d-bca-\frac12cb^2-\frac12bda-db^2}{a^2+ab+b^2} \\
        \end{bmatrix}$ with $||W_2||=\frac{\sqrt{(-2ca^2-a^2d-cab-2adb+2c)^2+(-a^2d-cab-2ca-2adb+2c)(-2db^2-cb^2-2cab-adb-2d)+(-2db^2-cb^2-2cab-adb+2d)^2}}{2(a^2+ab+b^2)^2}$

Everything in $W_2$ terrifies me and Im hoping for someone to confirm its right or wrong before I attempt normalizing this mess.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: I know this doesn't answer the question you've asked. Actually, you didn't ask a question -- you just expressed a hope. And I'm not the guy to support that hope. But anyhow...

You have to find an orthonormal basis. Suppose just for a moment that I asked you to do that for $V = \mathbb R^2$ with the usual inner product. What would you do?

If you asked *me* that, I'd say something like "$[1, 0]$ and $[0, 1]$", not some general thing with $a$s and $b$s in it.

Have you considered trying to make a particular concrete orthonormal basis? A good first step would be finding one unit vector. Actual real-number coordinates -- no variables. Can you do that?

Comment: I can. Would that satisfy the request for finding an orthornormal basis? Nothing was specified other than what I wrote above.

Comment: If *I* were the one who wrote the question, it'd sure satisfy me. If I wanted the thing you seemed to be doing, I'd say "Algebraically describe all possible orthonormal bases" or "parameterize the set of all possible ...", etc.  But I cannot say what the person who asked this question wants -- that's a social problem, not a mathematical one.

Comment: @JohnHughes: it would be far easier to describe all possible orthonormal basis in terms of just one easy to write basis and orthogonal matrices.

Comment: @tomasz: I agree, but wanted to describe a way in which OP's current work might be useful. I wasn't certain that OP would know what a matrix that's orthogonal wrt a nonstandard inner product would actually mean. But I did know that OP understood G-S. :)

Comment: I mean orthogonal in the usual sense, i.e. $AA^T=I$.

Comment: Right...but those are "the right things to multiply by" only if the OP's inner product is rotation-invariant (which it might well be---sure looks that way to me!), and OP would need to understand THAT as well. But i think it might well be worth writing this up as an alternative answer if you felt the urge.

Comment: @tomasz I would be interested in seeing this as an alternative answer as well.

Comment: @Aksel'sRose: I don't think that would be an answer to this question. But this is short enough for a comment. If $v_1,\ldots, v_n$ are an orthonormal basis with respect to a given inner product, then every other orthonormal basis is given by $w_1,\ldots,w_n$, where $w_i=\sum_{j} a_{i,j} v_j$, where $(a_{i,j})$ are the coefficients of an orthogonal matrix. This is true (more or less) by definition.

Comment: That seems wrong. Let $B = \begin{bmatrix}1 & 0 \\ 0 & \frac{1}{4}\end{bmatrix}$, $v_1 = e_1$, $v_2 = 2e_2$. Then $v_i^t B v_j = \delta_{ij}$, so the $v$s are an orthonormal basis for $B$. Now let $A = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} \begin{bmatrix}1 & -1 \\ 1 & 1\end{bmatrix}$; then $w_1 = c_1\begin{bmatrix}1 \\ 1\end{bmatrix}, w_2 =  c_2\begin{bmatrix}-1 \\ 1\end{bmatrix}$, and $\langle w_1, w_2 \rangle = w_1^t B w_2 = \frac{c_1c_2}{4} \ne 0$. So rotating an orthonormal (wrt $B$) basis by an orthogonal (in the standard inner product) matrix yields a non-orthogonal basis.